# Illegal State Exception when creating new Bufferstrategy

Tags: java, buffer, illegalstateexception

When I am trying to figure out how to use bufferstrategies, and overall just improving how I write my code and cleaning things up. When I run the following code, I get an error when I "createBufferStrategy(3)"

```
    package Game1Test;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Base extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean running = false;
    int ticks = 0;

    public Base(JFrame f) {
        setSize(f.getWidth(),f.getHeight());
        start();
    }

    public void start(){
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    public void stop(){

    }
    public void run(){
        while(running){
            ticks++;
            System.out.println(ticks);
            render();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g;
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        bs.show();
    }



}
```

The Base is then added with:

```
package Game1Test;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen extends JFrame{

    public final int GAME_WIDTH = 400;
    public final int GAME_HEIGHT = 400;
    public Dimension gameDim = new Dimension(GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT);
    final String gameName = "Test";

    public Screen(){
        setSize(gameDim);
        setTitle(gameName);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen s = new Screen();
        s.add(new Base(s));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
    at Game1Test.Base.render(Base.java:46)
    at Game1Test.Base.run(Base.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone please tell me why this is happening? and maybe a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: per the API, this exception is thrown if the component is not displayable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#createBufferStrategy%28int%29), this exception is thrown if the component is not displayable. In this case, that's when `Canvas.peer` is `null`. Taking a look at the `peer` field reveals that

> The peer is set when the `Component` is added to a
>   container that also is a peer

Since you are starting the update thread from your component's constructor, `render` could be called before your component is ever added to another container which would mean the `peer` is `null`, and then an `IllegalStateException` would be thrown.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid, but when is the component added, that's what I am confused about, when shuold I call the render method?

Comment: You should only call the `render` method *after* `Base` has been added to a container. In the code you showed us, `Base` is never being added to a container.

Comment: I just added the base code, would it be better If I put it all in one class?

Comment: @grimrader22 The problem is that in between the time where you create `Base` and it is added to `Screen`, the update thread you started may have already called `render`. You either need to call `start` separately from `Base`'s constructor or add `Base` to the `JFrame` in `Base`'s constructor before calling `start`.

Comment: so I shuold call the start method, In the main class where the main method is?

Comment: @grimrader22 Yup, make sure you call it after adding your `Base` to `Screen` though.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with this error and with the code you writing you missing a frame function.

Add where your frames are (ex: `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`) and add the function `frame.add(game);`

In this example, mine is `Display game = new Display();` but depending on what your variable for the new display is, it might vary.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same exception, but i found out that it was because my JFrame visibility was accidentally set to false.

so puting in setVisible(true); fixed it.